# Sharepoint Ports

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, tcp, udp

I am installing Sharepoint 2007 and I want users to be able to sign into it from outside.

I need to know what ports do I need to open and do I need UDP or TCP or both?

Comment: How will the users authenticate to SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only need the (inbound) TCP port that your website is running on (80 or 443 if using SSL typically.)